# Angular httpTestingController.expectOne throws even though httpClient.get was called

Tags: angular, testing

I have this simple function inside a service:

```
getReports(url: string): Observable<Report[]> {
    return this.http.get<Report[]>(url);
}
```

My test is as follows:

```
  it(`should call http request`, function() {
    spyOn(httpClient, 'get');
    const fakeUrl = 'https://reports.url/';
    service.getReports(fakeUrl);

    expect(httpClient.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(fakeUrl);
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(fakeUrl);
  });
```

The first expectation passes (so `httpClient.get` was called with the `fakeUrl`, but the controller's `expectOne` failed:

`Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: https://reportss.url/", found none.`

Any idea why angular's testing controller doesn't recognize my call?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you spyOn the httpClient if you use `HttpTestingController`? If you want to assert that the right HTTP-method was used I'd suggest asserting the method from the `req` that you received from the controller: `expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET')`

Comment: @jBuchholz I've added the spy to show the function is being called. I've written the full answer and the explanation why `expectOne` is throwing in this case.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error it seems that the issue stems from the fact that `expectOne` (and `matchOne` at that) only work if there's a subscriber to the `http` request.
So this will throw an error:

```
httpClient.get(fakeUrl);
const request = await httpTestingController.expectOne(fakeUrl);
```

But this will work:

```
httpClient.get(fakeUrl)
   .subscribe(() => {});
const request = await httpTestingController.expectOne(fakeUrl);
```

This happens because the `http` observable is considered `cold` as long as there are no subscribers to it. The moment you subscribe to the observable, the observable becomes `hot` or `open` and then `expectOne` can find it.